# What caused process.hrtime() hanging in nodejs？

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu

Here is the code:

```
var process = require('process')
var c = 0;
while (true) {
    var t = process.hrtime();
    console.log(++c);
}
```

Here is my environment:

nodejs v4.2.4, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Oracle VM virtualbox v5.0.4 r102546 running in Windows 7

This loop can only run about 60k to 80k times before it hangs. Nothing happens after that.

In my colleague's computer maybe 40k to 60k times. But shouldn't this loop continues forever?

I was first running a benchmark which tests avg execution time of setting up connections, so I can't just get the start time at first then end time after everything finished.

Is this related to the OS that I use?

Thanks if anyone knows the problem.

==========================================================

update 2016.4.13:

One day right after I raised this question, I realized what a stupid question it was. And it was not what I really want to do. So I'm gonna explain it further.

Here is the testing structure:

I have a node server which handles connections.Client will send a 'setup' event on 'connect' event. A Redis subscribe channel will be made at server side and then make some queries from db, then call client's callback of 'setup' event. Client disconnect socket in 'setup' callback, and reconnect on 'disconnect' event.

The client codes use socket.io-client to run in backend and cluster to simulate high concurrency.

Codes are like these:
(some of the functions are not listed here)

```
[server]
socket.on('setup', function(data, callback) {
  queryFromDB();
  subscribeToRedis();
  callback();
}

[client]
var requests = 1000;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  var count = 0;
  var startTime = process.hrtime();
  socket = io.connect(...);
  socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('setup', {arg1:'...', arg2:'...'}, function() {
      var setupEndTime = process.hrtime();
      calculateSetupTime(startTime, setupEndTime);
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    if (count++ < requests) {
      var disconnectEndTime = process.hrtime();
      calculateSetupTime(startTime, disconnectEndTime);
      socket.connect();
    } else {
      process.exit();
    }
  }
}
```

At first the connections could only make 500 or 600 times. Somehow I removed all the hrtime() codes, it made it to 1000 times. But later I raised the number of requests to like 2000 times (without hrtime() codes), it could not finish again.

I was totally confused. Yesterday I thought it was related to hrtime, but of course it wasn't, any infinite loop would hang. I was misled by hrtime.

But what's the problem now?

===================================================================
update 2016.4.19

I solved this problem.

The reason is my client codes use socket.disconnect and socket.connect to simulate a new user. This is wrong.

In this case server may not recognize the old socket disconnected. You have to delete your socket object and new another one.

So you may find the connection count does not equal to disconnection count, and this will prevent our code from disconnecting to redis, thus the whole loop hang because of redis not responsing.

Comment: Just tried it on node 4.2.4 on windows 10, got over a million executions before I decided to stop it..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an infinite loop - at some point this will always exhaust system resources and cause your application to hang.

Other than causing your application to hang, the code you have posted does very little else. Essentially, it could be described like this:

```
For the rest of eternity, or until my app hangs, (whichever happens first):
    Get the current high-resolution real time, and then ignore it without doing anything with it.
    Increment a number and log it
Repeat as quickly as possible
```

If this is really what you wanted to do - you have acheived it, but it will always hang at some point. Otherwise, you may want to explain your desired result further.

Comment: yes, I realized what a stupid question that was. I updated my question, plz check. now it may explained myself well.

Comment: "at some point this will always exhaust system resources and cause your application to hang." --- what resources exactly does it exhaust?